# Argument #2 ($wp_query) must be passed by reference

Tags: wordpress

Can someone help me fix these errors, please?

Warning: title_like_posts_where(): Argument #2 ($wp_query) must be passed by reference, value given in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324

Warning: title_filter(): Argument #2 ($wp_query) must be passed by reference, value given in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324

Warning: title_like_posts_where(): Argument #2 ($wp_query) must be passed by reference, value given in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324

Warning: title_filter(): Argument #2 ($wp_query) must be passed by reference, value given in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324

Warning: title_like_posts_where(): Argument #2 ($wp_query) must be passed by reference, value given in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324

Warning: title_filter(): Argument #2 ($wp_query) must be passed by reference, value given in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324) in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1435

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324) in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1438

This is the line 324 of the file wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php

`$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );`

This is the full code:
https://paste2.org/v6mfE9wU

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is maybe PHP version issue. can you mention your PHP version ?

Comment: See here how to get the full stack trace
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/332654/236977

Comment: I'm using the latest wordpress version with PHP 8.1